# Sorting Arraylist with multiple data types by date (numeric)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

This is what I have. Im scanning the txt and passing it to an array as a string (per line). I need to sort by date

```
   package stocktest;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 */
public class StockTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();

        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("transactions.txt");

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                String data = input.nextLine();
                 aList.add(data);
                System.out.println(aList);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.format("File does not exist/n");

        }
    }

}
```

Each line in transaction.txt looks like this

buy,1/2/2002,IBM,30,135.00

I need to sort the list by date.
What do you think I should do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you should sort the array

Answer (score 0):

first of all why dont you try to parse each line by "," and put it to a class that will have a states and methods, by that you can use comparator to sort an array list see my example.

> `private List<OrderDTO> orderDTOs;`

```
public class OrderDtoDateDescComparator  implements Comparator<OrderDTO>  {
    @Override
    public int compare(OrderDTO orderDTO, OrderDTO other) {
        if (orderDTO.getDateCreated() != null && other.getDateCreated() != null) {
            return orderDTO.getDateCreated().compareTo(other.getDateCreated());
        } else if (orderDTO.getDateCreated() != null && other.getDateCreated() == null) {
            return 1;
        } else if (orderDTO.getDateCreated() == null && other.getDateCreated() != null) {
            return -1;
        } 
        return 0;
     }
}
```

> `Collections.sort(this.orderDTOs, new OrderDtoDateDescComparator());`

see now that will be easy. as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cool use case for a Comparator.

```
Collections.sort(aList, new Comparator<String>() {

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
        try {
            Date d1 = format.parse(s1.split(",")[1]);
            Date d2 = format.parse(s2.split(",")[1]);
            return d1.compareTo(d2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
});
```